# Concatenate distinct values from several columns to one column in Java spark dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have the below spark dataframe.

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4 Column_5
1        A        A        Y         C
2        B        D        N         E
3        A        C        N         Z
4        F        G        Y         H
```

My reqired output is a dataframe with single column with duplicates removed from  column 2 3 and 5. Column_5 should be filtered and added to output when column_4 is Y. if it's N, then column_5 values should be ignored.

Required Output Dataframe

```
Column_1
A
B
F
D
C
G
H
```

What I tried so far:

I did this by dropping duplicates in each column. Applying filter on column 4 and finally doing a union all on all columns to get a final output dataframe with a column.

Is there a better way to do this in Java spark. Possibly without using UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add required columns & filters inside `array` & `explode` data. You will get final result.

```
df.show(false)
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|Column_5|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|1       |A       |A       |Y       |C       |
|2       |B       |D       |N       |E       |
|3       |A       |C       |N       |Z       |
|4       |F       |G       |Y       |H       |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

```
df
.select(
    explode(
        array(
            col("Column_2"),
            col("Column_3"), 
            when(col("Column_4") === "Y",col("Column_5")).otherwise(col("Column_2")
        )
    )).as("Column_1")
)
.distinct
.orderBy(col("Column_1").asc)
.show(false)

+----------+
| Column_1 |
+----------+
|A         |
|B         |
|C         |
|D         |
|F         |
|G         |
|H         |
+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Union for each column can be used:

```
df.select("Column_2")
  .union(
    df.select("Column_3")
  )
  .union(
    df.select("Column_5").where($"Column_4" === "Y")
  )
  .distinct
```